# Baby Rudin Theorem 4.29 query

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification, real-numbers

Rudin state's Theorem 4.29 along with the proof (see attached). Note I've only captured the proof up to where I have a query [image]

In the above how does combining (27) and (28) produce $|f(t) - A| < \epsilon$? I have

$A - \epsilon < f(x - \delta) \leq f(t) \leq A \Leftrightarrow - \epsilon \leq f(t) - A \leq 0$. I can't seem to get the $\epsilon$ on the right hand side of the inequality?

**After initial post**:

Rather then do a separate post, I am trying to prove the $f(x+) \inf_{x < t < b}f(t)$ part of (25).

Attempt:

$f(t)$ is bounded below by $f(x)$ where, $ x < t < b$ . Hence has a greatest lower bound $B$? $B \geq f(t)$. We need to show that $B = f(x+).$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. By definition of greatest lower bound, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x < t + \delta < b$ and $ B \leq f(t + \delta) \leq B + \epsilon$

Do I then say $B \leq f(t + \delta) \leq f(x)$? (to get an equation like 28).

Combining the two inequalities I get: $ |f(x) - B| < \epsilon$

Thus $f(x+) = B$?

Thanks.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is positive, therefore you have $\epsilon \leq f(t) - A \leq 0 \color{red}{< \epsilon}$

Comment: @MartinR Well now i feel stupid! I should do math so early in the morning! Thanks

Comment: That's a very good book to learn mathematics.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes it has been good, especially for self-study. Does my proof for the infimum approach look correct? I think I might have made some sign errors?

Comment: @MartinR Is my attempt at the infimum case correct? Thanks